# os.path.normcase intrepreting backslashes as escaping sequence?

Tags: python, os.path

(For the purpose here, I'm using Python 2.7.13 on Windows.)

I was told that [user input strings are automatically read as raw string literal here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664176/convert-string-stored-in-variable-to-raw-string). However, using a simple example:

```
def test (filename):
  return(os.path.normpath (filename))

test('Y:\Projects\14. MOON-301\Neoantigen\normal-10NB-tumor-10TB\normal-10NB-tumor-10TB-lib.txt')
'Y:\\Projects\x0c. MOON-301\\Neoantigen\normal-10NB-tumor-10TB\normal-10NB-tumor-10TB-lib.txt'
```

Which acts like `normpath` is treating `filename` as a string literal rather than a raw string literal. Of course I can use `eval` to coerce it back into raw string literals, but is there a more elegant way to do it?

Comment: `os.path.normpath` isn't interpreting backslashes. Python string literal syntax is doing that.

Comment: Use a `r'raw\string'`

Comment: Using a raw string is indeed the appropriate approach here, because you are using string literals

Comment: If you're in one of the rare cases where you really do need backslashes for the path - forward slashes are usually fine, even on Windows - then raw strings are a perfectly okay way to go about it. Just remember that if you need a trailing backslash, you have to provide that by concatenating a second string.